# hyperlink on php

Tags: php, wordpress, href

I'm working on a WordPress template and need to add a hyperlink to the cartoon bubble at the top of the page. The bubble, as far as I can tell, is php. Where do I insert the href?

```
<h1><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
```

The href should point to [www.ojaivalleynews.com](http://www.ojaivalleynews.com)

The blog url is [www.ovnblog.com](http://www.ovnblog.com) if you want a visual on the bubble. I've used firebug to ispect, but alas I don't know enough about php to make sense of it.

### Update

I missed the second line of code regarding the above question, and based off of the suggestions here, have made corrections to this line and it works.

```
<h1><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
<div id="bubble"><p><a href="http://www.ojaivalleynews.com/" target="_blank"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "insert the href"?  Does bloginfo('url') include the domain name?  Also, are bloginfo() return values escaped?  If they aren't, see the htmlspecialchars PHP function.

Comment: Rereading your question several times makes me think you aren't the writer of this code.  In that case, are you trying to replace the URL of that link?  If so, change "<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" to "http://www.ojaivalleynews.com/".

Comment: You are right, I did not right the code, just trying to make a couple of tweaks. I followed your advice and changed the initial href to point the correct url, but nothing changed. In doing so I wrote over the <?php_etc; should I only write over the ('url') portion?

Comment: @rashneon, See @Laodimos's answer, @Scott Evernden's answer, or @Paolo Bergantino's answer (which are all the same thing).

Comment: Thank you, but none of those options are working either. The bubble still does not behave like a link. Thank you all for your suggestions though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rashneon, look for the following HTML (search header.php for 'bubble')

```
<div id="bubble">
  <p>Click for OVN Homepage!</p>
</div>
```

replace that with

```
<div id="bubble">
  <p><a href="http://www.ojaivalleynews.com/">Click for OVN Homepage!</a></p>
</div>
```

@Endlessdeath - no, delightfully WordPress mixes a bunch of functions which print with a bunch of functions which return values. So yes, it really is supposed to be `<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>` - see [the default theme file](http://trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-content/themes/default/header.php#L43)

Answer (score 3):

just replace the

```
<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/
```

with

```
http://www.ojaivalleynews.com
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<h1><a href="http://www.ojaivalleynews.com/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
```

I think that's what you want, but I can't be sure...

Answer (score 2):

if you want to replace this with another -static- link it should be:

```
<h1><a href="http://www.ojaivalleynews.com"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
```

Comment: He didn't escape the ".  bloginfo('url') may have printed "http://google.com" (without the quotes), and after that he adds a slash to make it "http://google.com/".  Probably meaningless as most web servers cause a redirect, but could be a security feature (some silly defaults for Apache, e.g.).

Answer (score 2):

In WordPress, bloginfo('url') gives you the url to your blog's home. "bloginfo" is the same as "echo get_bloginfo".

If your blog's main page is http://www.ojaivalleynews.com, that's what it'll output. Else, if http://www.ojaivalleynews.com has nothing to do with your blog, just replace  with the static url like others recommended.

If you're a new to WordPress and you're going to use it a lot, see http://codex.wordpress.org/

** UPDATE **

Updating your update, bloginfo('description') gives you your blog's description/headline (generally under your blog's title). If your blog is http://www.ojaivalleynews.com, you're outputing the url dinamically in the first link and staticly in the second. If not, you're giving your blog's description as text on the link to http://www.ojaivalleynews.com.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have to echo the return values of the function?

```
<h1><a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>/"><?php echo bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
```

Comment: Not if the function itself echo's the return value.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that myself.  However, I'm not sure if that's the problem (which isn't too clear in the first place).

Comment: no. wordpress bloginfo function reads like this: function bloginfo($show='') {
 echo get_bloginfo($show, 'display');
} - in other words, the function echoes the output.